# How do I solve this exponential equation? $5^{x}-4^{x}=3^{x}-2^{x}$

Tags: transcendental-equations

How do I solve this exponential equation?
$$5^{x}-4^{x}=3^{x}-2^{x}$$

Comment: $x=1{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: $x=0,1$ seems to be the only real solution. for $x\gt 1$, the L.H.S. growth rate is more than that of R.H.S. and for $x\lt 0$, L.H.S. $\lt $ R.H.S

Comment: @WillJagy You forgot $x = 0$

Comment: No, it is a religious prohibition. Well, it will be, once I have finished designing the religion.

Comment: @BackinaFlash: Will forgot nothing. :-)

Comment: you should add whether x is from he integers, reals or complex. If it is from the integers then Euler's totient gives also an answer, optimally if you rewrite $5^x-3^x=2^x(2^x-1)$

Comment: $x=0,1,-\infty$ by lucky inspections

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{5^x-4^x}{5-4} = \frac{3^x-2^x}{3-2}$$

> Now use the Lagrange Mean Value Theorem over the intervals $(2,3)$ and $(4,5)$. The equality holds only when $x \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: @BunsOfWrath I think this was a pointless edit on a very highly-upvoted answer that's more than two years old.

Comment: @pjs36 Yeah, maybe. It wasn't immediately obvious to me that $(2,3)$ and $(4,5)$ were intervals, so I edited for that. The other changes were just because the TeX was a bit sloppy.

Answer (score 16):

$$5^x - 4^x = \int_4^5 x y^{x-1} \,dy$$
$$3^x - 2^x = \int_2^3 x y^{x-1} \,dy$$
$$= \int_4^5 x (y-2)^{x-1} \,dy$$
So the difference between $5^x - 4^x$ and $3^x - 2^x$ is
$$ \int_4^5 x (y^{x-1} - (y-2)^{x-1})\,dy$$
In the integrand here, since $y \rightarrow y^{x-1}$ is monotone whenever $x \neq 1$, the
expression $(y^{x-1} - (y-2)^{x-1})$ will either be always negative or always positive if $x \neq 1$, in which case the integral itself will be nonzero unless $x = 0$.

We conclude that as long 
as $x \neq 0$ or $1$, $(5^x - 4^x) - (3^x - 2^x)$ is nonzero. Hence $3^x - 2^x = 5^x - 4^x$ only when $x = 0$ or $1$.

After writing all this out, I probably prefer the mean value theorem approach, but hey it's good to have more than one way of looking at a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f:[0.25,2] \to \mathbb R \,;\, f(a)=(3.5-a)^x+(3.5+a)^x \,.$

Then $f'(a)=x[(3.5+a)^{x-1}-(3.5-a)^{x-1}]$.

**Claim:** If $x \notin \{ 0,1 \}$ we have $f'(a) \neq 0 \forall a $.

Indeed, in this case $f'(a) =0 \Rightarrow (3.5+a)^{x-1}=(3.5-a)^{x-1} \Rightarrow a=0$ which is not in our domain.

This proves that for $x \neq 0,1$, $f$ is one to one on our domain, and hence

$$f(0.5) \neq f(1.5) \Rightarrow 3^x+4^x \neq 2^x+5^x $$

Answer (score 1):

Only method I can think of is trying graphically. Since their slopes vary a lot after $(1,1)$ and before $(0,0)$, all possible intersections can lie between these two points.

How to find all those possible intersections is something I'd need to work out.